# VLOOKUP error code 9, subindex out of interval

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

After looking for some solutions and trying different ways to develop the `VLOOKUP` function in Excel VBA, I still receive the same error.

I have a worksheet called "priceDATES" where I have to find the *id* of each date that is in the other worksheet.

```
id_date = Cells(cursor_fecha, 1).Value 
id_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(id_date, _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("priceDATES").Range("A1:B500"), 2, False)
```

The error message:

> Error number 9 in execution time
>   Subindex out of interval

Comment: Do you really have a sheet called `priceDATES`?

Comment: @GSerg yes i have a sheet called pricesDATES and yes is not necessarily to overwrite the variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this procedure and let me know if it works:

```
Sub add_vlookup()
Dim i As Long
With Sheets("inserts")
    For i = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        .Cells(i, 3).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & _
        .Cells(i, 1).Address & ",priceDATES!$A:$B,2,0)"
    Next
End With
End Sub
```